# how to clear form values history of mozilla firefox using php?

Tags: php, browser-history

In Mozilla Firefox when we enter values then history is maintain Unless

> user Click Go TOOLS->CLEAR RECENT HISTORY  .

If there is way to clear values history using php

I use

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

But It not Clear Mozilla Values History.

Comment: @bourbaki, I couldn't agree more. +1

Comment: You could put in a javascript snippet to reset all the form values to blank/null when the page loads. Even if there's `value=""` bits, or auto-filled "remembered" values, the Javascript would blank those out. Of course, if the user's got JS disabled, then ...

Answer (score 4):

The question i belive is about default-form values.

You have two options:

Either add a randomized suffix to your field-names,

```
<input type="text" name="username_AFTH" .../>
```

Add autocomplete="off" as attribute,

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"
```

Not sure if all browsers supports it though..

regards,
//t

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know about, but you can use javascript to redirect (of course with php as a "backup") to prevent to keep the page in history.

```
window.location.replace('http://page.to.redirect/to');
```

^ Does not store the page in history! Good luck!

Comment: I think OP was referring to form values... Nice try thou.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, If you can clear user history visited sites this mean you can control his browser and must be this a bug in browser.

Answer (score 0):

May be this help:

```
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Mon, 30 Dec 2001 05:00:00 GMT");
```